# How I can save a Firebase user if he log the first time with Facebook or Google login?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-signin

hi have a android app with Facebook and Google login. I use Firebase Auth and Realtime database and want check if someone exist in the database. If the User login first time with Facebook or Google I want to create a new user in the database with a nickname.

Here is my code:

```
 public void saveUserToDatabase(User newuser){

        DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");

        mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                String userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid(); //Holt sich die ID von Firebase

                /*
                * Es wird geprüft ob das Element schon in der Database existiert
                * */

                if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(userId)){

                    Log.d(DATABSE_FIREBASE,"Benutzer ist bereits in der Datenbank angelegt!");

                }else{
                        Log.d(DATABSE_FIREBASE,"Benutzer ist noch nicht in der Datenbank angelegt!");

                    // hier muss der nickname übergeben werden

                    mDatabase.child(userId).setValue(newuser);

                        Log.d(DATABSE_FIREBASE,"Ein neuer Benutzer mit der Email: " + newuser.getEmail() + " wurde in der Datenbank angelegt");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Log.d(DATABSE_FIREBASE,"Fehler beim Zugriff auf die Datenbank...");
                finish();
            }
        });
```

But the user will not save in the database. What can I do?

Comment: You need to create nickname for the first time user in firebase?

Comment: Stack Overflow is notoriously inefficient as a remote debugger. So in order to get help, you'll have to do some more work yourself and tell us what's going on. Did you step through the code in a debugger? Does it reach `onDataChange()`? If so, which branches does it go into?

Answer (score 0):

Use shared preferences to store that information, that information will persist if the app in still installed.

```
Context context = getActivity();
SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
getString(R.string.preference_file_key), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE)


SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putString(getString(R.string.user_saved), "google|facebook");
editor.commit();
//Read from Shared Preferences

SharedPreferences sharedPref =getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String choice = sharedPref.getString(getString(R.string.user_saved), defaultValue);
if(choice.isEmpty()) Log.d("TAG","first time");
```

Comment: just check in the onCreate if the key stored is empty, if so then it is their first time.